# Kubernetes: CreateContainerConfigError secret not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

> kubectl apply -k .

```
service/wordpress created
service/wordpress-mysql created
persistentvolumeclaim/mysql-pv-claim created
persistentvolumeclaim/wp-pv-claim created
deployment.apps/wordpress created
deployment.apps/wordpress-mysql created
```

> kubectl get pods

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS   AGE
wordpress-7f7bf85b9c-7wmcq         0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          14m
wordpress-mysql-7d5f9bb46c-fqd6p   0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          14m
```

> kubectl describe pods

```
Name:             wordpress-7f7bf85b9c-7wmcq
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             docker-desktop/192.168.65.4
Start Time:       Thu, 18 May 2023 12:53:21 -0700
Labels:           app=wordpress
                  pod-template-hash=7f7bf85b9c
                  tier=frontend
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Pending
IP:               10.1.0.47
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.0.47
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/wordpress-7f7bf85b9c
Containers:
  wordpress:
    Container ID:
    Image:          wordpress:4.8-apache
    Image ID:
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CreateContainerConfigError
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST:      wordpress-mysql
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'password' in secret 'mysql-pass'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-v2dq2 (ro)
      /var/www/html from wordpress-persistent-storage (rw)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  wordpress-persistent-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  wp-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-v2dq2:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  15m                 default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
  Normal   Scheduled         15m                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/wordpress-7f7bf85b9c-7wmcq to docker-desktop
  Warning  Failed            12m (x12 over 15m)  kubelet            Error: secret "mysql-pass" not found
  Normal   Pulled            8s (x70 over 15m)   kubelet            Container image "wordpress:4.8-apache" already present on machine


Name:             wordpress-mysql-7d5f9bb46c-fqd6p
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             docker-desktop/192.168.65.4
Start Time:       Thu, 18 May 2023 12:53:20 -0700
Labels:           app=wordpress
                  pod-template-hash=7d5f9bb46c
                  tier=mysql
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Pending
IP:               10.1.0.48
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.0.48
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/wordpress-mysql-7d5f9bb46c
Containers:
  mysql:
    Container ID:
    Image:          mysql:5.6
    Image ID:
    Port:           3306/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CreateContainerConfigError
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'password' in secret 'mysql-pass'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from mysql-persistent-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-dpj4p (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  mysql-persistent-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  mysql-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-dpj4p:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------          ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled       15m                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/wordpress-mysql-7d5f9bb46c-fqd6p to docker-desktop
  Normal   SandboxChanged  15m                 kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  Failed          13m (x12 over 15m)  kubelet            Error: secret "mysql-pass" not found
  Normal   Pulled          4s (x74 over 15m)   kubelet            Container image "mysql:5.6" already present on machine
```

Error: secret "mysql-pass" not found

> kubectl get secrets

```
NAME                    TYPE     DATA   AGE
mysql-pass-kkcc2b926b   Opaque   1      3h36m
```

> kubectl describe secrets

```
Name:         mysql-pass-kkcc2b926b
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
password:  6 bytes
```

The secret was created by:

```
secretGenerator:
- name: mysql-pass
  literals:
  - password=123456
```

Comment: The error message is quite descriptive: there is no secret with name `mysql-pass`.

Comment: mysql-pass-kkcc2b926b is created from mysql-pass.

Comment: secretGenerator:
- name: mysql-pass
  literals:
  - password=123456

Comment: `mysql-pass-kkcc2b926b != mysql-pass`. I suspect that this secret is created thorugh a `kustomization`, which - by default - appends a suffix to the secrets. If so, you may want to add `generatorOptions: disableNameSuffixHash: true` to the `kustomization.yaml` that generates the secret. See [here (`github.com`)](https://github.com/ConSol/s4-infra/blob/main/deployments/bases/artemis/kustomization.yaml#LL23C1-L24) for an example).

Comment: ...although if you're also creating the wordpress deployment with Kustomize, this should all work *without* disabling the suffix hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should declare the secret to avoid the suffix:

```
kind: Kustomization
generatorOptions:
  disableNameSuffixHash: true
  labels:
    foo: bar
secretGenerator:
- name: mysql-pass
  literals:
  - foo=bar
```